# How ioc, interfaces and implementations work

Tags: go, interface

I am trying to figure out interfaces in GoLang.

Being familiar with how it all works in Java i.e. interface, implements allowing for a mock and a full implementation. I am a bit confused on how I can tie things together in Go.

For example, I am trying to implement `AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI` connector. I have created `PAAPI` interface and also another file that provides an implementation.

I then have a struct `config`. I then created a file with method signatures that implement `PAAPI` and are based on `config` i.e. `config` implements `PAAPI`.

All that happens in the same package. But from an outside perspective, how can I then go and implement a mock of `PAAPI` it seems bizarre that everything is linked on the `config` struct.

Any code example would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'ts not quite clear what you are asking to me. Can you elaborate on your question? Maybe add some code?

Comment: Don't program Java in Go. Start concrete (not with an interface). Extract interface where appropriate. Take a look at how the stdlib does things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you're saying your implementation is coupled to the `config` struct instead of the interface. If that is the case, simply replace the argument that uses the `config` to the interface, in this case `PAAPI`.

In the below code, instead of the `DoSomethingWithStruct` function definition, what you want is probably the `DoSomethingWithInterface` function definition.

```
type PAAPI interface {
    Foo() // just a stub method
}

type Config struct {}

func (config *Config) Foo() {
    // do something
}

func DoSomethingWithStruct(config Config) {
    // do something
}

// you probably want a method that uses your config through the interface
func DoSomethingWithInterface(config PAAPI) {
    // do something
}
```

To take it another step further, if in an external package, you want to implement the interface simply define another struct that adheres to the interface. Like the below:

```
type ExternalConfig struct{}

func (config *ExternalConfig) Foo() {
    // do something
}
```

A couple notes about this that differs from Java is that there is no explicit `implements` keyword in Go. It is based off a familiar principle in dynamically typed programming languages instead, which is basically [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). It implicitly knows that the interface is implemented by the struct at compile time.

Based on the two previous snippets of code, now you can call `DoSomethingWithInterface(ExternalConfig{})`. Note that I inlined the instance of `ExternalConfig` here but you can create it with actual credentials and pass it into `DoSomethingWithInterface` in the same way. Hope this helps. Also, feel free to comment to ask for clarity if I'm not quite hitting the target.